Access a txt local file with d3
I am new with D3, Javacript, and HTML.
The repository of my project is as follows:
Project:

facebook_combined.txt
index.html
network.js

I am trying to access facebook_combined.txt from index.html to try to do a first visualization of it.
Here is the console when I execute the index.html
This is index.html
This is network.js
I have tried to reproduce other project online but I always get this error. My guess is that I am trying to access a local file from the server which doesn't have access to it.
I didn't find a way to run the html locally or to put the txt file online in a way that the server can reach it.

That's an image, not HTML. Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Excuse me, I won't do it again

You cannot fetch local files because this would raise dramatic security concerns. (Imagine a script could just retrieve a file "C:\mypasswords.txt" ...)
If you want this to run locally, include the contents of "facebook_combined.txt" directly into your script or html.
Otherwise your html and script file as well as the txt need to be accessible online.

You can absolutely access local files, you just need to spin up a web server on localhost such that the file in question is in a subdirectory of the server directory. And you need to reference them by relative path.

Thank you! I succeeded by using the visual studio code extension called vscode-preview-server.
